# Period liquid in a U-tube

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I have to find the oscillation period of a liquid inside a u-shapped tube.
All I have is the density = $\rho$, liquid length = $l$ and the section = $A$

The only way I found is by the conservation of energy $E = U + K$.

Can I say the mass = $l\cdot A \cdot \rho$

then, $E = \frac{1}{2}mgy^2 +\frac{1}{2}m\dot y^2 $

I'm sorry if all that makes no sense, I don't really know how to approch that.

Any help will be appreciate.

[image]